# How to use xodus blobs in a multi-thread-scenario? And should they be closed?

Tags: blob, vert.x, xodus

*First question:*

The [documentation states](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#blobs) that you should not close the `InputStream` that you retrieved by the `getBlob` method. The javadoc of this method states, that you should close it. Who is right?

*Second one:*

I'm using xodus in an "asynchronous environment", where blob-streaming is suspended/resumed in a cooperative-multitasking-style using callbacks and backpressure-detection (in my specific case vertx write queues mixed with drain-handlers). So, while I'm never accessing the blob's `InputStream` from different Threads at the same time, I may access them from different Threads in time slots that are guaranteed to be isolated timewise from each other. Is this save?

In other words: The [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#blobs) told me that "Concurrent access" to the same blob is not possible - does this mean different Threads at the same time, or different Threads at any time?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not close the input stream, as the documentation states. I've fixed the javadoc, thanks for noticing.

"Concurrent access" is meant as an access to a single instance of `InputStream` from different threads at the same time. Cooperative multitasking should work fine if the access to the stream is really successive and the [happens-before order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) is kept.

Comment: great! Thank you so much!